# Referencing urls of specific resources in eclipse java web application

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets, applet

Can anyone show me how to specify urls of specific resources using java servlets?  I am using eclipse.  The code below produces a servlet whose main page can be viewed at the url:

```
http://www.mysite.com/myapp/thisservlet/
```

Instead, I want to be able to access the specific jsp at the url:

```
http://www.mysite.com/myapp/thisservlet/thishere.jsp
```

Also, I would like for thishere.jsp to be able to call code that is located somewhere else in my application directory structure in eclipse.  For example, within my eclipse project, thishere.jsp is located in the myapp/web/WEB-INF/web folder.  However, ThatThereApplet.java is located in package myapp.myapplets, which is located in my eclipse project in the path myapp/src/myapp.myapplets/ThatThereApplet.java.  Alternatively, I have also bundled ThatThereApplet.class in test_applets_1.jar, which I placed in the myapp/web/WEB-INF/lib folder in my eclipse project before adding it to adding it to my application's build path using the context menu in eclipse.

Can anyone show me how to alter the code below so that it does what I have described above?

Here is the code for ThisServlet.java:

```
package myapp.web;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ThisServlet extends HttpServlet {

   private RequestDispatcher jsp;

   public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
      ServletContext context = config.getServletContext();
      jsp = context.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/thishere.jsp");
   }

   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
   throws ServletException, IOException {
      jsp.forward(req, resp);
   }
}
```

Here is the code for thishere.jsp:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Applets Go Here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Gonna put an applet below:</h1>
<applet code="myapp.myapplets.ThatThereApplet.class" archive="test_applets_1.jar" width="500" height="500">
<h1>The applet should be above this line.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code that I encapsulated within test_applets_1.jar and added to the build path:

```
package myapp.myapplets;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ThatThereApplet extends Applet {

   int width, height;

   public void init() {
      width = getSize().width;
      height = getSize().height;
      setBackground( Color.black );
   }

   public void paint( Graphics g ) {
      g.setColor( Color.green );
      for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) {
         g.drawLine( width, height, i * width / 10, 0 );
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the relevant part of web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>thisservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>myapp.web.ThisServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>thisservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/thisservlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

EDIT:

---

I followed Sudhakar's great advice and changed web.xml to indicate:

```
<url-pattern>/thisservlet/thishere.jsp</url-pattern>
```

However, when I load thishere.jsp in my browser, the application is not able to find the location of the applet, so the applet does not load even though thishere.jsp does load.  I ran the Java Console when I loaded thatthere.jsp in my web browser, and the following is the error log it produced:

```
load: class myapp.myapplets.ThatThereApplet.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myapp.myapplets.ThatThereApplet.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myapp.myapplets.ThatThereApplet.class
```

Can anyone show me how to change the code above so that the application is able to find ThatThereApplet.class and successfully load it into thishere.jsp?

Answer (score 1):

change the `url-pattern` in web.xml to

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>thisservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/thisservlet/thishere.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: +1 for a very helpful suggestion.  Thank you.  I edited my original posting above with the result of using your suggestion.  Can you help me with the second part of my original posting above, given the information that I placed in my edit to the original post above?  I want the applet to load in thishere.jsp

Comment: what java version are you using ? Can you also try including the the applet tag into a standalone html file and open it

Comment: I am using Java 6.  I just now included the applet tag into an html file and got the same results as I got with thishere.jsp .  Any ideas?

Comment: Did u give direct file path to the jar in the html file, can you include the stand alone html you tried ?

Comment: I loaded the html file by putting the following url into my browser: mysite.com/myapp/myapplets/thishere.html .  The stand alone html that I tried is the exact same code listed for thishere.jsp in my original posting above.  In addition, I also just tried archive="myapp/test_applets_1.jar" in the <applet> tag and got the same identical error shown above from the Java Console.

Comment: is your applet directly accessible via url , they can you provide that  url in archive=""   in the standalone html

Comment: I do not understand your most recent comment.  My applet, along with my application, are on a local computer, and are not yet uploaded to the web.  I am testing them with eclipse and tomcat server.  I tried it with archive="", but that resulted in the same error message.  I think I have enough code and info above for someone to recreate this on their own computer.  I imagine this has to do with eclipse's way of organizing resources.